# Why Windows won’t install on new machine?

Tags: windows, installation, asus

I have an Asus 670E and a Ryzen 7600x3d for ages I just kept an old install that went through 2 other motherboards, another processor and 2 RAM kits.

Due to the mess my machine became I decided to format and install a clean copy of Windows. I get stuck on the following screen:

[image]

I says a media driver needed is missing. I went to asus website and added all the possible files [from here](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/tuf-gaming/tuf-gaming-x670e-plus-wifi/helpdesk_download?model2Name=TUF-GAMING-X670E-PLUS-WIFI) to another USB flash drive and they are simply not found. I've tried to disable both NVMe and SATA to no good. I just realized I might need to remove the GPU?

I checked the BIOS options that Ramhound mentioned but I still have the same issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are likely trying to install Windows 11 while CSM is enabled.  This error has **nothing** to do with NVMe drivers, SATA drivers, or GPU drivers. Windows 11 must be installed in UEFI mode which requires, Secure Mode to be enabled and CSM to be disabled.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "they are simply not found"? Did you browse to the driver files? If you press shift+f10 to open cmd, and run `diskpart` then `list volume`, does it show the flash drive you booted to? If not, you will need to add the USB drivers

Comment: Also check the drive mode. If "RAID" or "Intel RST" you do indeed need additional drivers. Try AHCI instead.

Comment: How did you create the installation disk?  The only process you should trust is the default options using Rufus or the Media Creation Tool directly from Microsoft. I am not sure how you disable NVMe if you are using a SSD, and you most certainly can't disable SATA, if your using a SATA HDD or SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it. Many things, you cannot use DD to burn a Windows iso.
I had to use rufus and select:

1. partition sheme MUST be GPT
2. Target system MUST BE UEFI (non CSM)

This opened the option to install but the system complained it was no, it cannot instal now cause the partition is mbr and needs to be gpt .

So to fix it:

- shift + f10 during the install that will open a cmd terminal enter

1. diskpart
2. list disk
3. select disk X
4. clean

And then I was able to install windows.